# Flex box is not working

Tags: css, flexbox, uc-browser

I used `display:flex;` in every `css` file of my site but now it is working fine in google chrome but in UC Browser(phone) it is not working.It is just skipping flex and showing items vertically.How can i correct this without changing the full coding of the site.

Thank you

Comment: In some browsers like safari, you need to use -webkit-. `display:-webkit-flex; -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;` ....

Comment: I want it to work for uc.

Comment: I do not know the **us**. But test the -webkit- it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that most web standards are not supported in UC browser along with the fact that it removes some css and js from web pages for faster page load.

Still, it uses WebKit as its rendering engine, so you can try to support Webkit as much as possible and you'll be good to go. Furthermore, tools like auto-prefixer will fix most of the cross-browser issues.

It's best to consider [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) to check which features are supported by your target browser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've structured your css. `display:felix;` doesn't work in all browsers. This is why it's important to research your css and browser compatibility.

Use this [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Use `display:-webkit-flex;`

Comment: I tried all this but still it is not supported in uc.

Answer (score 0):

I think `display:flex;` isn't supported in UC.

Comment: Flexbox might not be supported but it will be available in prefixed format like

`display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;`

Answer (score 0):

i think this is right for flex
display:-ms-flexbox; //for ie older version
display:-webkit-flex; //for chrome older version,firefox older version,safari
display:-webkit-box; //for android ucbrowsers forever,i think you gonna try this line

display:flex; //for all new versions browsers like chrome 66 and above firefox 46 and above ie11 and above eventhough  safari , opera and some more newversion browsers can support this line

you can go for this line in ucbrowsers in mobile or pc => display:-webkit-box;
if you want inlie-flex try this and it's works display:-webkit-inline-box;